# Can we have a factory class as spring bean and have a factory method returning multiple spring beans based on the condition?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, factory

I want to return multiple spring beans based on the condition in the factory class.

Is this a good practice?

Any better ways to write the following piece of code?.
Any other design patterns suitable here?

Below is the code snippet:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.Resource;


@Component
public class InstanceFactory {

    @Resource(name = "instance1")
    private Instance instance1;

    @Resource(name = "instance2")
    private Instance instance2;

    public Instance getService(Condition condition) {
        if (condition.one() && condition.two()) {
            return instance2;
        } else {
            return instance1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me. Though it probably depends on what your condition actually is.

Comment: This looks like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you know about FactoryBeans? or depending on the condition, profiles might be useful. for there to be a clear answer there should be more details.

Comment: Thanks @biziclop and Nathan Hughes. I will look into the FactoryBeans

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Factory Pattern is meant to create objects but what you are returning are objects already create somewhere else (Spring in this case). If you want to create beans that will be managed by Spring there are several ways:

@Conditional(YourConditionImplementation.class): This annotation added on a method of a @Configuration annotated class will allow you to create a bean when the given condition is fullfilled. Example here: https://javapapers.com/spring/spring-conditional-annotation/

You can uses as well BeanFactory to inject the definition of your bean (DefinitionBean) into the container. Example here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/bean-definition.html

Now, if you want an object that determine what object of type Instance fits better for some need then your approach is ok, but it is not technically a factory :)

Comment: It’s not recommend to use @ConditionOnMissingBean not in spring boot auto configuration library etc

Comment: It is recommended according to spring doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html. Anyway nobody said anything about spring-boot. At the moment it's only spring and @conditional with a custom condition class.

Answer (score 0):

When designing something like that I would face that solution considering two design patterns:

- Strategy pattern: In order to replace repetitive *if else* every time you need to evaluate more instances.
- Decorator pattern: Trying to make every condition as configurable as possible. They can be composed (decorated) for one or more predicates.

Considering these two pattens you might achieve something like this:

First, define which conditions will identify a given instance:

```
public enum InstanceType {
    INSTANCE_TYPE_1(Condition::isOne, Condition::isTwo),
    INSTANCE_TYPE_2(Condition::isOne, Condition::isThree),
    ...;
    private List<Predicate<Condition>> evaluators;

    @SafeVarargs
    InstanceType(final Predicate<Condition>... evaluators) {
        this.evaluators = Arrays.asList(evaluators);
    }

    public boolean evaluate(final Condition condition) {
        return evaluators.stream().allMatch(it -> it.test(condition));
    }
}
```

Then, you should link every instance implementation to an specific instance type:

```
@Component
public class InstanceOne implements Instance {
    @Override
    public InstanceType getType() {
        return InstanceType.INSTANCE_TYPE_1;
    }
}
```

Finally, a class to config where defining the relation between types and instances as EnumMap

```
@Configuration
public class InstanceFactoryConfig {
    @Autowired
    private List<Instance> instances;

    @Bean
    public EnumMap<InstanceType, Instance> instancesMap() {
        EnumMap<InstanceType, Instance> instanceEnumMap = new EnumMap<>(InstanceType.class);
        instances.forEach(i -> instanceEnumMap.put(i.getType(), i));
        return instanceEnumMap;
    }
}
```

Thus, you InstanceFactory can be replaced to something like this:

```
public class InstanceFactory {
    @Autowire
    private final EnumMap<InstanceType, Instance> instancesMap;

    public void getInstance(Condition condition) {
        instancesMap.get(getInstanceType(condition)).doSomething();
    }

    private InstanceType getInstanceType(Condition condition) {
        return Arrays.stream(InstancesType.values())
            .filter(evaluator -> evaluator.evaluate(condition))
            .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Instance type not found"));
    }
}
```

As you can see, you InstanceFactory is less prone to be modified. This means, every time you need you add a new instance implementation you only need to modify the InstanceType enum. Hope this is helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring existing FactoryBean interface and implement your own logic 
It’s one of the best approaches to create beans in spring framework
Here is the link with example :

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean

Answer (score -1):

See: 
[Spring Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

The active profile is set by properties and based on the value you assign to the profile, Spring will load different beans for the same interface.
So it might be exactly what you need.